# 'dsrun' is not recognizes as internal or external command

Tags: dspace

I'm trying to install DSpace on Windows following [documentation](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSPACE/Installing+DSpace+on+Windows). I'm getting `error: dsrun is not recognized as internal or external command` when I try to create administrator account. I'm positioned at DSpace/bin and there are  files: buildpathi.bat, dspace,dspace-info.pl,dspace.bat,log-reporter,make-handle-config and start-handle-server. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

That's a mistake in the documentation. Use the command like this:
`C:\dspace\bin\dspace.bat dsrun org.dspace.administer.CreateAdministrator`

Answer (score 0):

Try dspace.bat create-administrator